# Flutter with firebase image upload issue

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

I had created a image upload application with firebase and flutter. When I am trying to upload the image to my firebase using the flutter app, but the image is not uploaded to the firebase. I cannot find the error.

this is the `createBlog.dart` file of my code file of my flutter application

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import '../services/blogCrud.dart';
import 'package:random_string/random_string.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

class CreateBlog extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateBlog({super.key});

  @override
  State<CreateBlog> createState() => _CreateBlogState();
}

class _CreateBlogState extends State<CreateBlog> {
  late String authorName, title, description;
  File? selectedImage;
  bool _isLoading = false;
  //XFile? selectedImage;

  BlogCrudMethods blogCrudMethods = new BlogCrudMethods();

  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      selectedImage = File(image!.path);
    });
  }

  uploadBlog() async {
    if (selectedImage != null) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      //uploading to the firebase storage
      Reference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child("blogImages")
          .child("${randomAlphaNumeric(9)}.jpg");

      final UploadTask task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(selectedImage!);

      var downloadUrl = await (await task).ref.getDownloadURL();

      print("this is url $downloadUrl");

      Navigator.pop(context);
    } else {}
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(
          children: const <Widget>[
            Text(
              "***Flutter",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
            ),
            Text(
              "Blog",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.blue),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
        actions: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              uploadBlog();
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
              child: Icon(Icons.file_upload),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: _isLoading
          ? Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      getImage();
                    },
                    child: selectedImage != null
                        ? Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                            height: 150,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                              child: Image.file(
                                selectedImage!,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        : Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                            height: 150,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)),
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.add_a_photo,
                              color: Colors.black45,
                            ),
                          ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 8,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Author Name"),
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            authorName = val;
                          },
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Title"),
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            title = val;
                          },
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Description"),
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            description = val;
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the `blogCrud.dart` file of my flutter application

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class BlogCrudMethods {
  Future<void> addData(blogData) async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("blogs")
        .add(blogData)
        .catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
}
```

if anyone can please help me .thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this plugin to set the image file path

```
path_provider: ^2.0.13
```

For Uploading, this worked for me

Import:

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
```

Uploading function

```
static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> uploadImage(
  String selectedImage) async {
   try {
       String fileName = basename(selectedImage);
       String? imageURL;
      var uploadData = await FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref()
      .child('images/$fileName')
      .putFile(File(selectedImage));
      imageURL = await uploadData.ref.getDownloadURL();
       return {
          'status': true,
          'data': imageURL,
       };
   } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
     return {
        'status': false,
        'message': e.message,
     };
   }
}
```